# How to hide certain Components for some Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to hide Header and Footer Component in some routes, e;g for `path="/invoice/:id/print"`

I have an app with this type of layout using react-router-dom v5

```
<Router>
        <Header />

        <main className="py-0 px-0">
          <div>
            <Container fluid>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
                <Route path="/invoices" component={Invoices} exact />
                <Route path="/invoice/:id/print" component={InvoicePrint} exact />
                <Route path="/billing/invoice/create" component={InvoiceCreate} exact />
                <Route path="*" exact>
                  <Error404 />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Container>
          </div>
        </main>

        <Footer />
      </Router>
```

The problem is if I go to

```
<Route path="/invoice/:id/print" component={InvoicePrint} exact />
```

Then Header and Footer also get rendered. But I want to hide them for this specific route. So how can I do that?

> I'm using react-router version 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on how many pages should render the Header and Footer components.
If you want to render them on just a few pages, the simplest solution will be to move them to the components/pages where you'd like to render them.

If you'd like to hide them in just one or two places you can use the `useRouteMatch` hook.

You can also build some abstractions to simplify the readability a bit: let's make the `Layout` component, which will accept a prop (like `renderHeaderAndFooter` (you can change the name of course )).

Layout component:

```
const Layout = ({ renderHeaderAndFooter, children }) => (
  <div>
    {renderHeaderAndFooter && (
      <Header />
    )}
    {children}
    {renderHeaderAndFooter && (
      <Footer />
    )}
  </div>
)
```

and the place of usage:

```
const HomeScreen = () => (
  <Layout renderHeaderAndFooter={true}>
    // make stuff
  </Layout>
)
```

```
const Invoices = () => (
  <Layout renderHeaderAndFooter={false}>
    // make stuff
  </Layout>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

simple way is to trigger your current route by using useRouteMatch in every component you want like:

```
 const match = useRouteMatch("/invoice/:id/print"); // import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";


 return !!match ? <></> : <Footer/> //or Header
```

check [this](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch)

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the Header and Footer components by adding a listener during the rendering phase of the component : `componentDidMount()`

Fetch the called component :
const shouldHide = useRouteMatch("/invoice/:id/print") || useRouteMatch("/other/route");

```
return (
 !shoudlHide && <Header />
)
```